# for... in object property comparison

Tags: javascript

Trying to make a simple deep comparison function and noticed that this block of code was returning false when it should be true. Added the console logs to find the flaw.

```
for(var prop in obj1){
    if(obj1[prop] !== obj2[prop]){
       console.log("obj1." + prop + " = " + JSON.stringify(obj1[prop]));
       console.log("obj2." + prop + " = " + JSON.stringify(obj2[prop]));
       return false;
    }
}

var obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: 1, object: 2}));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}));
// → true
```

results are

```
obj1.here = {"is":"an"}
obj2.here = 1
false
obj1.here = {"is":"an"}
obj2.here = {"is":"an"}
false
```

So I can tell the for... in prop method seems to be working because it's comparing 'here' for example. This is good. I think they're equal in the second console.log, so I think the answer is to use a different way of comparing them, because it's still evaluating them by reference possibly?

Comment: You need to use recursion and apply your `for..in` comparison loop to object values you find, just like you're doing for the top-level objects. To put another way: if you expect structurally-identical objects (like `{is:"an"}` and a different `{is:"an")`) to compare equally, why did you write this function in the first place?

Comment: Oh! You mean because 'here' is an object inside obj?

Comment: @ZackLucky it might help you looking at this post also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript